# change and initialise variables in a function

Tags: php

I was wondering if it's possible to change and initialize variables in a function without passing arguments to the function. Here is what I want to achieve:

```
$foo = 'Lorem';
$array = array();
foobar($foo);
function foobar(){
    if (strlen($foo)== 1)
        $bar = 'Ipsum';
    else
        $array[] = 'error';
}

fubar();
function fubar(){
    if (empty($fouten))
        echo $bar;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$foo` is a local (uninitialized) variable inside a function. It is different from the global variable `$foo` (`$GLOBALS['foo']`).

You have two ways:

```
$foo;
$bar;
$array = array();

function foobar(){
    global $foo, $array, $bar;
    if (strlen($foo)== 1)
        $bar = 'Ipsum';
    else
        $array[] = 'error';
}
```

or by using the `$GLOBAL` array …

This is not really good practice though and will become a maintenance nightmare with all those side effects

Answer (score 1):

Functions in php can be given arguments that have default values.  The code you posted as written will give you notices for undefined variables.  Instead, you could write:

```
function foobar($foo = null) {
    if($foo) { // a value was passed in for $foo 
    }
    else { // foo is null, no value provided
    }
}
```

Using this function, neither of the below lines will produce a notice

```
foobar();
foobar('test');
```

Comment: Should check `if(is_null($foo))` as an empty string casts to `false`. Depends on requirements of course, but noteworthy.